# C# / DateTime /

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

There are a lot of events available for registration on my applications page. This method returns all active events. but there is a problem, for example, there is an event today at 11 am. after 11 am it logically should not be shown, but it shows as active. And it doesn't hide until after midnight. So, it becomes inactive when the date changes (i.e. the end of the period does not take into account the hours)...What is the best way to change the DateTime so that the event becomes inactive after a given hour, and not the next day?

```
public IPagedList<Domain.Event> SearchEventsPublic(long[] eventCategoryTypeIds = null,
                                          long[] locationIds = null,
                                          DateTime? startDate = null,
                                          DateTime? endDate = null,
                                          int pageIndex = 0,
                                          int pageSize = int.MaxValue)
    {
        var query = _eventRepository.Table;
        // get event by filter
        if (eventCategoryTypeIds != null && eventCategoryTypeIds.Length > 0)
            query = query.Where(c => eventCategoryTypeIds.Contains(c.EventCategoryId));

        if (locationIds != null && locationIds.Length > 0)
            query = query.Where(c => locationIds.Contains(c.LocationId));

        var minDate = DateTime.Now;
        if (startDate.HasValue && startDate.Value > minDate)
        {
            minDate = startDate.Value.Date;
        }
        query = query.Where(c => c.StartDateTime >= minDate ||
                                (c.PrePurchase && (c.ParentId == null || c.ParentId == 0)));

        if (endDate.HasValue)
        {
            var maxDate = endDate.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
            query = query.Where(c => c.StartDateTime <= maxDate ||
                                (c.PrePurchase && (c.ParentId == null || c.ParentId == 0)));
        }

        query = query.OrderBy(c => c.PrePurchase ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(c => c.StartDateTime);
        return new PagedList<Domain.Event>(query.AsQueryable(), pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
```

Comment: `minDate = startDate.Value.Date;` What do you think `.Date` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `startDate.Value.Date` so it will definitely return the date part of `DateTime`. If you want to compare time part also then compare complete `DateTime`. For endDate `endDate.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);` it will also return date part. You also need to compare full `endDate`.

```
public IPagedList<Domain.Event> SearchEventsPublic(long[] eventCategoryTypeIds = null,
                                  long[] locationIds = null,
                                  DateTime? startDate = null,
                                  DateTime? endDate = null,
                                  int pageIndex = 0,
                                  int pageSize = int.MaxValue)
{
    var query = _eventRepository.Table;
    // get event by filter
    if (eventCategoryTypeIds != null && eventCategoryTypeIds.Length > 0)
        query = query.Where(c => eventCategoryTypeIds.Contains(c.EventCategoryId));

    if (locationIds != null && locationIds.Length > 0)
        query = query.Where(c => locationIds.Contains(c.LocationId));

    var minDate = DateTime.Now;
    if (startDate.HasValue && startDate.Value > minDate)
    {
        minDate = startDate.Value;
    }
    query = query.Where(c => c.StartDateTime >= minDate ||
                        (c.PrePurchase && (c.ParentId == null || c.ParentId == 0)));

    if (endDate.HasValue)
    {
        var maxDate = endDate.Value.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
        query = query.Where(c => c.StartDateTime <= maxDate ||
                        (c.PrePurchase && (c.ParentId == null || c.ParentId == 0)));
    }

    query = query.OrderBy(c => c.PrePurchase ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(c => c.StartDateTime);
return new PagedList<Domain.Event>(query.AsQueryable(), pageIndex, pageSize);
}
```